# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg' everytime i try to download anaconda3 on macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3

I am trying to download anaconda3 terminal version for a 64bit mac OS Catalina to use for python 3.7, and i keep running into the error:

```
Unpacking payload ...
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback:                    
'''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 368, in _queue_management_worker
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
'''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 484, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 611, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 388, in __get_result
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
[16126] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

all i am trying to do is install anaconda3 on my laptop to use for a sentiment analysis program that only runs on python 3.7 (otherwise i would use google colab). this is my first time trying to run python on terminal, and it has been such a headache.
i have no idea what is going wrong. i cannot access jupyter notebook without anaconda, and anaconda refuses to install correctly. any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me nuts.

are there any better apps through which i can use python 3.7 without having to go through this pain??? extremely frustrating.

Comment: i should add i've tried downloading anaconda 3 times now, and everytime it takes up a few GBs of my space, while not working. is there another place i can use python 3.7 without having to break my computer?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you are running out of space

Answer (score 1):

I met the question on x86, when I use `sudo sh Anaconda.sh`, it runs well.
But when I just use `sh Anaconda.sh`, it returns this problem.
Why dont use `sudo sh Anaconda.sh` for me? Because after install Anaconda, when you need install packages, it warns that you need `sudo conda xxx`, it's so inconvinient.
You can try `sudo` to install Anaconda to see if we have the same problem.

Comment: `sudo` will install the `anaconda` into the administrator's space,such as `/home/root/anaconda3`,just do `sh Anaconda.sh` will install into the login user's space,such as `/home/user1/anaconda3`.If the `root`  home space enough,but `user1` home space not enough,error show you meet.